# Can no longer switch keyboard layouts in xfce

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

This appears to be a surprisingly complex problem, and worse, I'm not sure if it was a configuration change that I made or if it was an update to ubuntu that caused the problem. I'm running Ubuntu Studio 14.04, all the latest updates (Linux version 3.13.0-30-lowlatency (buildd@kissel)), on an Asus K55A. Here's what happened:

- My keyboard lost some keys (due to extreme tropical humidity), namely the main "enter" key.
- Using the numpad enter key ("KPEN") didn't work in vim (I don't know how vim intterpreted the keycode that it sent (which was 104), but it kept inserting an "M")
- Thus, I dug into my xkb files and changed all KPEN mappings from `KP_enter` to `Return`
- Simultaneously, I executed a bunch of backlogged updates that I hadn't done for the last month due to low bandwidth.
- At some point after these two events, my KP Enter key started working in vim (presumably because of the changes I made), but I stopped being able to switch keyboard layouts.

Now, here's a more detailed description of the problem:

- In my config, I have - and have had, since nothing has changed in my config - my default keyboard layout as `EN_US` and a secondary layout as `LATAM` (spanish). To switch between them, I use `shift+caps lock`. The xfce4-xkb-plugin worked as expected.
- After this mysterious event, my config still looks identical, but pushing `shift+caps lock` does nothing but activate caps lock. Also, the xfce4-xkb-plugin doesn't show any other layout options, despite there being a second layout defined in my keyboard settings.

And here's what I've done for diagnostics:

- Used a **different keyboard**. **Fail:** the  problem persists (and didn't expect otherwise, since all symptoms point to a software problem)
- Configured **only latam layout** in my keyboard settings (i.e., removed the us keyboard as an option). **Fail:** keyboard layout was still in english.
- Switched to **TTY1** using  `ctrl+alt+F1` and entered `sudo loadkeys latam`. **Success: latam characters work**.
- Switched back to **TTY7** (i.e., my **desktop environment**), **fail:** found keyboard was still in english.
- In my desktop environment, I **opened up xterm** and did `sudo loadkeys latam` again. **Fail: No errors, but didn't work** either.
- I then did **`sudo loadkeys --verbose latam > /tmp/latam.keys`** and **`sudo loadkeys --verbose us > /tmp/us.keys`** and **ran a diff** on the two files to verify that they were indeed different. **The files were different** (this makes sense, and suggests that loadkeys is doing its job correctly).
- I then **created a new account**, test-me, and logged in to see if the problem was system wide. **Fail: the problem is system-wide.** There was no way to switch layouts.
- Searched for **xkb in processes list. Nothing showed up.** Maybe that's normal, but I at least expected an xkb daemon to handle translations and stuff.
- I ran `setxkbmap -v 10 latam`. **Fail**: I got the following output:

  ```
  setxkbmap -v 10 latam
  Setting verbose level to 10
  locale is C
  Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
     Using command line, ignoring X server
  Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
  Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
  Success.
  Applied rules from evdev:
  rules:      evdev
  model:      pc105
  layout:     latam
  Trying to build keymap using the following components:
  keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
  types:      complete
  compat:     complete
  symbols:    pc+latam+inet(evdev)
  geometry:   pc(pc105)
  Error loading new keyboard description
  ```

Unfortunately, I don't know a whole lot about the key translation subsystem, so I'm a bit stuck now. What it looks like to me is that maybe for some reason the system is just discarding the whole user config and falling back on the system settings, but then I don't know why `loadkeys` wouldn't work in xterm.

Anyway, I'll leave it at that. I'll be happy to provide any new information. Thanks!

-kael

Comment: It's not surprising that `loadkeys` didn't work in X, as it only changes the console keymap, not X keyboard layout. Try `setxkbmap latam` to see if X actually have the layout. There is no xkb daemon, xkb is part of X11.

Comment: Ok, cool. I didn't know about setxkbmap. I'm updating my question to add that output.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unfortunately, after a few days without luck, I decided to just reinstall the os. I installed, ran all the updates, changed KPEN to Return again, and ended up with a functioning keyboard. I have no idea what happened before, so unfortunately I can't provide any insights to anyone else trying to fix this.... Sorry!